# JSON Map, delimiter colon (:) is replaced by arrow (=>)

Tags: json, delimiter

I am posting a request, with JSON map within it, to an external system, but due to some reason delimiter colon (:) gets replaced by an arrow (=>).

```
"map": {
                    "key-1": "value-1",
                    "key-2": "value-2",
                }
```

Data displayed in external system's UI

```
{"key-1"=>"value-1", "key-2"=>"value-2"}
```

Data when read from an external system via postman

```
"map": "{\"key-1\"=>\"value-1\", \"key-2\"=>\"value-2\"}"
```

Does anyone knows whats going on over here?

Comment: How do you create that request? Is that PHP?

Comment: No, its a rest request in java... tried  via postman as well, but problem persists